# Count with condition in calculated member (MDX)

Tags: count, mdx

I have the following diminsions tables:
close_date with these columns: close_date, Year, month
open_date with columns: open_date, Year, Month
and a fact table (for IT Support requests) with many columns like: ref_num, duration, open_date, close_date, user

I want to count the number of request which have been opened and closed in the same month. What will be the MDX query?